Is it possible to inject dynamic (user-generated) javascript code into a web page from an extension? The chrome-scripting API seems to say it can
The Chrome scripting API claims that this should work, as long as the JavaScript does not try to interact with the JavaScript local to the site.
I have tried this, and every possible variation:
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((message, sender, sendResponse) => {
  if (message.action === 'injectCode') {
    chrome.scripting.executeScript({
      target: { tabId: sender.tab.id },
      func: new Function(message.code)
    });
  }
});

I tried to get ChatGPT to do it (after providing the chrome scripting API docs in full), and it confidently said it could, but nothing worked.  Full conversation at:
https://chatgpt.com/share/9e57dc70-cc21-4d73-b923-ec104b0a8a8d
This is for a development tool I use locally.

Function and eval are disabled for MV3 extensions outside of sandboxed pages but those don't have access to executeScript. You can only use chrome.userScripts API or run the code inside the main world of the page subject to the site's CSP. P.S. ChatGPT is delusional.
